# Visualizing the center of mass of a stickman toy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

I have this metallic stickman toy that is able to balance itself. I am curious about its center of mass. Can anyone help me visualize a rough position to where the object's center of mass is with an explanation to it?

[image: Image of toy]

Answer (score 5):

It is below the feet

[image: fig1]

You can measure where it is, by measuring the period of oscillation when pushed slightly.

$$T = 2\pi \sqrt{ \frac{\ell}{g} } $$

is the equation for the period $T$ of a pendulum, and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity to get $\ell$ the distance from the pivot (feet) to the center of mass.

Comment: Thanks, do you have an explanation to why the center of gravity is that low? I expected it to be somewhere in the middle of the feet.

Comment: @netbeansnewbie - they key here is to concentrate as much mass as possible below the contact plane, and in doing so it makes the stick figure stable. All it matters is that the center of mass is below the pivot point. Now, visually you might get tricked by the big thick base, but that is not part of the moving mass and you need to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The center of mass equation is

$$\vec R_{\rm cm}=\frac {m\,(\vec R_1+\vec R_2)+M\,(\vec R_3+\vec R_4)}{2\,(m+M)}=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\  {\frac {m\,h+M\,H}{m+M}}
\end {array} \right] 
$$

and with $~H\approx 2\,h~$

you obtain

$$\left(\vec R_{\rm cm}\right)_y=\frac{h\,(m+2\,M)}{m+M}> h$$

thus it is above $~h~$

assume $~M\approx m~\Rightarrow~\left(\vec R_{\rm cm}\right)_y=\frac 32 h~$

Notice

that this is not the exact solution but very good  approximation

Answer (score 0):

center of mass is found mathematically by adding each mass of particle present in the toy multiplied with respect to the distance from the center.
$$R_{com}=\frac{1}{M}.\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}r_{i}$$  n is the number of particles present in the toy , M is total mass , $m_{i}$ is individual mass of particle in concert and $r_{i}$ distance from center of the toy.

Intuitively you can try to get a rough idea by finding how to balance it with a finger laying the toy horizontally so center of gravity would not affect the measurement and the place where you find the most stability is the approximate center of mass. If finger doesn't work(most probably) try to use some material like wood (which is not very wide) and keep it on a table , pressing the wood by one hand. Let the wood be out from the table so that you can measure Centre of mass. You can keep the horizontal toy on the wood and try to get an approximate of center of mass!

Comment: To find the center of mass, tie a string to the object and let it hang - the center of mass lies on the line directly under the string. Now do it again, tying the string to some other point (that wasn't on the first line) - the center of mass lies where first and second lines intersect.

Comment: That is very interesting , is there any reason why that intersection of 2 lines is Center of mass ? @NuclearHoagie

Comment: Because by tying a string to one point of the object, that point becomes fixed in space. Then the attitude of the object is determined only by its center of mass, which will be directly below the fixed point - but anywhere on that line. This latter part is solved by repeating the measurement with another point and thus another line to obtain their intersection.

Comment: ah I can understand it thank you @zovits !

Comment: @NaveenV No matter how you hang the object, the center of mass must always lie on the line below the string. When you hang it from two different spots, you get two different lines, each line representing an infinite number of candidates where the center of mass could be. But there is only one single point that lies on *both* lines. If the CoM was anywhere else, it would imply that you could hang the object and have the CoM not directly under the string.